# How to distinguish two realm Db in the app?

Tags: ios, swift3, realm

I have two database in the app , both are realm . I wanted to distinguish both of them . one is just for reading purpose.

I have this code to read the preloaded database :

```
    let defaultPath = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL?.path
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "default1", ofType: "realm")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: defaultPath!), let bundledPath = path {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(atPath: bundledPath, toPath: defaultPath!)
        } catch {
            print("Error copying pre-populated Realm \(error)")
        }
    }

    let realm = try! Realm()
    let array = Array(realm.objects(Medicine.self))
    print(array.count)
```

But when I add new model 'Person' into realm . I wanted to distinguish in which database I am writing. following is the code for writing into database for 'Person' model.

```
@IBAction func addButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    // MARK: Functions
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New Patient", message: "Enter Patient Name", preferredStyle: .alert)
        var alertTextField: UITextField!
        alertController.addTextField { textField in
            alertTextField = textField
            textField.placeholder = "Patient Name"
        }
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { _ in
            guard let text = alertTextField.text , !text.isEmpty else { return }
             let personObj = Person()
              personObj.name = text
             self.realmPatientArray.append(personObj)
            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(personObj)
            }
            self.realmTableView.reloadData()
        })
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

When I opened the realm file it is showing only one model which was originally there i.e ('Medicine'). I am not getting where this 'Person' model is getting stored.

Comment: Are you re-copying your bundled database into the default file path after you writ the `Person` object? It's not clear what you're trying to do, since in both code snippets you're opening and using the same database (`Realm()` just opens the Realm with the default configuration).

Comment: The problem is that when I deleted app and installed again , the app is not copying the default1.realm file to the default.realm

Comment: I have actually solved the distinguishing part